# IE7, inline-block и float: right

Tags: веб-программирование, html, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Есть следующий код: http://jsfiddle.net/XyQ75/2/. Его смысл: `<div class="wrapper">` принимает ширину таблицы, `<div class="right">` таким образом выравнивается по правому краю таблицы. Работает в Chrome, Firefox, IE8+. В IE7 `<div class="right">` уползает в правый край экрана. Хак с `hasLayout` для эмуляции `display: inline-block` (в IE7 такое значение свойства `display` не поддерживается) не помогает. Вопрос: можно ли добиться описанного результата в IE7 **не прибегая к JavaScript**?

Comment: может немного оффтоп, но - А зачем оно вам нужно? Концентрация IE7 в нете чрезвычайно мала, т.к. он был включен в Vista, а виста не пошла.

Если же заказчик требует, то извините...

Comment: @Gedweb таковы требования к проекту. Убедить заказчика в том, что поддержка IE7 ему не нужна, достаточно проблематично.

Comment: попробуйте bootstrap, там есть костыли для IE

Comment: @Gedweb подключать bootstrap я не буду, проект уже готовый, я занимаюсь лишь его доработкой. Но вот посмотреть, как подобное реализовано в bootstrap я попробую.

Comment: @fori1ton, правильная мысль

Comment: Копание в коде Bootstrap ни к чему не привело. Кажется, он тоже не умеет так делать. Придётся всё-таки использовать JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так http://jsfiddle.net/XyQ75/3/

Comment: Просто, как всё гениальное) Таблица, конечно, утяжелит код, но эта жертва по сравнению с использованием JS для выравнивания элементов вполне приемлима.